# Improper use of Stokes and Divergence Theorem. Find the problem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Could someone point out what is *wrong* with this equality? Assume that $\mathbf{F}$ is continuous (and hence, its partial derivatives).

$$\begin{align}
\oint \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{s} & =^\text{by Stokes} \iint_S \nabla \times \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{S} \\
&=^\text{by Div} \iiint_V \nabla\cdot( \nabla \times \mathbf{F} ) \, dV \\
&=\iiint_V 0 \,dV \\
&=0\\
&\implies \oint \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{s}= 0 \; \forall \mathbf{F}
\end{align}$$

Since we assumed $\mathbf{F}$ and its partials are all continuous. But obviously this is wrong if $\mathbf{F}$ is non-conservative. But everything seems to agree. What went wrong?

**EDIT**. For a refinement of the problem. Let me specifically state that $S$ is a closed surface with a boundary curve that is also closed. So $V$ here is the volume of that surface and since $S$ is closed it has a volume

Comment: $S$ is not the boundary of a volume.  Edit: Or, as Schmitty says, $\partial S$ is empty.

Comment: Isn't $V$ is the volume over the entire enclosed surface?

Comment: You need to be more explicit about what curve/surface/volume you are integrating over. Perhaps take a simple example, say a circle, and tell us what you think the domains of the integrals are.

Comment: @RahulNarain, take a circle to be the boundary. Then I attach a hemisphere to that boundary to make my surface. My volume integral will integrate the volume of that hemisphere

Comment: @jak If you attach a hemisphere without base, you cannot use the divergence theorem. If you attach a hemisphere with base, then your surface is closed, hence the boundary is empty, not the circle you started with.

Comment: @Tunococ, why does Schmitty say my surface is closed then?

Comment: @jak: Tunococ also said it is closed.

Comment: Schmitty starts from not knowing what your original curve is, and says that since you applied the divergence theorem, your intermediate surface must have been closed, so its boundary -- your original curve -- must have been empty. On the other hand, if you start with the curve being a circle, then the surface you obtain will not be closed, so you cannot apply the divergence theorem after that.

Comment: If I take my hemisphere to be my surface (which is closed), then I say for my base (which is a circle), I'll attach a circle that is the boundary for the open surface of the open hemisphere or the disk itself. Then doesn't the Div Thrm still hold?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stokes and Gauss' Divergence theorem on a closed smooth surface in $\Bbb R^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687643/stokes-and-gauss-divergence-theorem-on-a-closed-smooth-surface-in-bbb-r3)

Answer (score 7):

Actually nothing is wrong with that.  You start with a vector field integrated over a closed curve.  Your first equality which does use Stokes's Theorem goes to an integral over a surface S for which your original curve must be the boundary. Your next equality uses the divergence theorem and goes to an integral over a volume for which your surface S must be the boundary implying S is a closed surface.  Since your assumptions indicate that S is a closed surface S doesn't have a boundary- or rather, the boundary of S is the empty set.  So the integral you started with is over the empty set----> hence it's zero.

Comment: But like Tunococ said, my surface is actually open

Comment: As Tunococ said for an open surface the divergence theorem doesn't apply which gives you the problem you were looking for.  In the case of a closed surface the argument is valid.  Whatever F is if you integrate it over the empty set you're going to get zero.

Comment: How could you integrate over the empty set (the boundary)? if it is closed? I am confused

Answer (score 5):

This is one of my favorite phenomena in multivariable calculus.  I remember noticing this when I was first learning the subject, and spent many hours wondering how this could be.

The explanation for this phenomenon lies in the following geometric principle:**

> The boundary of a boundary is empty.

This geometric fact is in some sense "dual" to the fact that $\text{div}(\text{curl}\,\mathbf{F}) = 0$ for all $\mathbf{F}$.

In particular, if you have a volume $V$ that bounds a surface $S$, then the surface $S$ cannot have a boundary curve.  Said another way, the boundary curve $C = \partial S$ is the empty set, so integrating anything over it is zero.

**Example:** In the comments, you consider a solid hemisphere $V$.  The boundary of $V$ will then be the surface of the hemisphere **and also** the disc base.  This closed surface (consisting of **both** the hemisphere surface and the disc base) does **not** have a boundary curve.

On the other hand, the surface which is just the hemisphere (without the base) does have a boundary curve: namely, the circle.  However, this surface cannot be said to enclose any volume.

---

**Note 1:** Typically when one talks about a "closed" surface, one specifically means a surface which does not have a boundary curve.  This is an unfortunate piece of terminology since the term "closed" can also refer to being a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$, and these two definitions are *not* equivalent.

For instance, the hemisphere together with its boundary curve (but not including the disc base) is a closed as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$, but is generally not called a "closed surface."  However, the hemisphere together with the disc base *is* a closed surface (and is also closed as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$).

** **Note 2:** This principle is somewhat vague as stated.  In order to make it precise, one needs to rigorously define the notion of "boundary."  This can be done in a couple of ways; some definitions will satisfy this principle, while others won't.  For now, let's not get into these details.

Comment: *This closed surface (consisting of both the hemisphere surface and the disc base) does not have a boundary curve.* Isn't it a circle?

Comment: No.  I understand your confusion, though a simple explanation escapes me... All I can say is: topologically speaking, the hemisphere together with the disc base is like a sphere that has been squashed and then pinched.  Certainly you wouldn't say that a sphere has a boundary curve, right?  Same thing here.

Comment: As another example, a (circular) cylinder together with both caps does not have a boundary curve.  However, a cylinder with no caps has a boundary consisting of 2 (disjoint) circles.  Still different is a cylinder together with one cap, which has boundary consisting of 1 circle (namely the circle that isn't capped off).

Comment: Isn't the cap bounded by a circle anyways?

Comment: Yes, the boundary of the cap is a circle.  But the boundary of a cylinder together with one cap consists of 1 circle -- namely, the circle that is the edge of the _uncapped_ side.  Is all of this clear?

Comment: I think I do. So in the original problem, after I'd applied the Div Theorem. I got 0 not just because div(curlF) = 0, but also the volume is 0?

Comment: I'm not clear as to the original problem.  What exactly is the surface you are given?  (Or what are the conditions on the surface?)

Comment: None. I started out with a circle on the xy-plane, then I attached a surface (in this case a hemisphere).

Comment: OK, so the surface you started with is the hemisphere (without the cap).  You cannot apply the Divergence Theorem to this surface because this surface is not closed (because the cap is not included).  On the other hand, if you start instead with the hemisphere together with the cap, then you can apply the Div Thm $\iiint \text{div}\, \mathbf{F}\,dV = \iint \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{S}$.  After that, you could apply Stokes Theorem if you wanted (assuming $\mathbf{F} = \text{curl} \mathbf{G}$) but your boundary curve would _not_ be the circle in this case: it would just be the empty set.

Comment: No, let's do this analytically perhaps. I start out with a sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ for $z \leq 0$, so in other words $z = +\sqrt{1-x^2 - y^2}$. The boundary is the unit circle on the xy-plane. Then I incorrectly applied the divergence theorem to the hemisphere because the hemisphere has no base to begin with. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right (except I think you mean $z \geq 0$) :-)

Comment: Yes I did. But was my original explanation of my mistake also correct? That *I got $0$ not just because div(curlF) = 0, but also the volume is $0$*? Btw, I checked in some advanced calc book and they also say that the concept of the "boundary" seems to be different in the context of Stoke's Theorem. It's by Folland

Comment: Intuitively, yes, I suppose you could say that.  I think it's more accurate, however, to say that the Divergence Theorem simply doesn't apply to the hemisphere (without cap), meaning that you shouldn't have gotten $0$ at all: the calculation should have stopped at Stokes' Theorem.  Said another way, the hemisphere doesn't have a well-defined volume.  And yes, I mentioned in my post that there are essentially 2 different definitions of "boundary" -- one for vector calculus (and differential geometry) and one for point-set topology.